# How do i put a per page theme in a special box/div?

Tags: custom-field

I am using 20-11 theme and i have the sidebar on the left, the main content center and now i would like to edit a php file (or not) to make a 3rd div to the right of the content. I'm unsure how i'll edit/style that.

But my bigger question is after i get that part done, how do i say on this page use this image in that box? For some reason i suspect i specify the image on a per page bases so i may can this feature. Do you guys have any ideas?

(i dont know what to tag this so feel free to change/fix it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... Buidling a second sidebar is a matter of CSS & HTML... all i can say about that is that you should think of the structure you want, then create a div before or after the content (Depends on the position) and change othere containers sizes so they would all fit.

**If you got something like this:**

```
<!--======= YOUR CSS ========-->
.bodyContainer { width: 960px; }
.left { float: left; width: 300px;}
.content { float: center; width: 650px;}

<!--======= YOUR HTML ========-->
<div class="bodyContainer">
    <div class="left">
    You left sidebar
    </div>

    <div class="center">
    Your Content
    </div>

    <br style="clear: left;" />
</div>
```

It Should turn into something like this:

```
<!--======= YOUR CSS ========-->
.bodyContainer { width: 960px; }
.left { float: left; width: 200px;}
.content { float: left; width: 550px;}
.right { float: left; width: 200px;}

<!--======= YOUR HTML ========-->
<div class="bodyContainer">
    <div class="left">
    You left sidebar
    </div>

    <div class="center">
    Your Content
    </div>  

    <div class="right">
    Your Right Sidebar
    </div>

    <br style="clear: left;" />
</div>
```

.
I can't build it for you cuz' it would take me some time but that the essence of it right?

As for the Image on the side... Once you a have a sidebar to the right you can define a new Thumbnail and call it into that div class="right"... that real easy and should be done like this:

**In your functions.php file:**

```
add_image_size('rsidebar-thumb', 600, 200, true); // 600=width / 200=height
```

.
**Then in you right sidebar paste this:**

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail('rsidebar-thumb'); ?>
```

.
And now you can enter an image for eash post with ease..

Comment: Nice. So instead of putting `<?php the_post_thumbnail('rsidebar-thumb'); ?>` anywhere i made a note for the user(s) to use the html part of the page editor and add in a A tag with the class sideimage. Then i use css with absolute to position it and it worked :)

Comment: Great man - Glad i could help :)